Words of wisdom on balancing flavors in a dish with multiple components?
I'm very fond of "bowl" recipes (like Buddha bowls) which involve multiple components prepared separately but combined at the final stage. Every variation involves some cooked and/or seasoned components, some fresh, and occasionally a dressing. Is there some sort of rule of thumb for knowing how much to cook and season, and how much to leave plain? I'd love to make my own, but I don't want to overwhelm the dish with too many competing flavors. (And I don't really "pick things up" just by reading or experience, I do best with a rule or basic idea that I can follow). Thanks!

Unfortunately there's no answer to this that wouldn't be entirely based on opinions, so this has been closed on that basis. It's also very, very broad, with hundreds of cuisines to choose from. As a basic approach I would pick a cuisine you like and use recipes.
